# Huge amount of imap-login netstat

Tags: email, email-server, dovecot, exim, netstat

When I run a `netstat -plantu` I have a huge amount of `ESTABLISHED imap-login`, perhaps 50 or 60 connection.

Some connections have in column `Send-Q` a big number like 3211206 or 114636 for example, and all other are at 0.

Is that normal?

For information we are in the factory 10 peoples who use thunderbird. We also have some php script who connect to inbox folder, maybe some connections aren't closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thunderbird uses multiple connections to allow faster and concurrent command execution. The default value of connections per account is 5, which explains the number of `imap` and `imap-login` processes you have.

You can decrease the value in *"Tools -> Account Settings -> Server Settings -> Advanced -> IMAP -> Maximum number of server connections to cache"* (cf. [Mozilla wiki](http://kb.mozillazine.org/IMAP:_advanced_account_configuration)).